# Multiple stacked full-width background images with Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put together a static webpage using Bootstrap 3.0.

The page is basically a narrative, and consists of a series of stacked sections with background images, with text and other images/elements overlaid on top.

[image: I've]

The page is just designed to be scrolled from top to bottom, and each section's background image should fill the horizontal width.

Later on, I'll also be adding parallax with the images using Skrollr (https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr).

However, right now, I'm struggling to get working HTML/CSS with Bootstrap.

Initially, I thought I could do something like this:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <section id="first">
        <div class="row annoucement col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <h1>The story of...</h1>
        </div>
    </section
    <section id="second">
        <div class="row gallery col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <!-- Image gallery boxes -->
        </div>
    </section
</div>
```

and then in the CSS:

```
    #first {
        background: url(img/1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

However, the background images aren't visible - the #first  element is 1140px x 0px, so the image isn't showing.

I suspect I'm not using the tag types correctly - any suggestions of how I can get the above layout working with Bootstrap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your markup for the grid system is incorrect, you should look at [the examples](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) from the docs, basically the `.row` should be a container element, also if you want the background to cover the whole page then you can't have the sections inside the container, this is what I'd suggest:

```
<body>
    <section id="first">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row announcement">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                     <h1>The story of...</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="second">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row gallery">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                    <!-- Image gallery boxes -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Though you may want to use a larger span size for your content, because I believe col-md-4 would be too small, but that's for you to decide :)

Comment: Cool, that's great, the images are showing up now =). Only thing is - the height is being set by the inside elements (e.g. <h1> The story of...</h1>), rather than the background image dimensions, so you only see a thin strip of the image. Is there a way to show the full vertical dimensions of the background image? (But still scale horizontally to fit).

Comment: not unless you set the height of the section to the height of the image, typically you would set a large padding on the top and bottom of the sections to increase their size

Comment: Aha, I thought there might be a way to fit to picture vertically. Ok, so I can set either `width` or `padding-bottom` on #first, so that it will fit the full background image. `width` seems be easier, since I just set it to the photo and don't need to worry about what's inside - however, you're saying that I should use `padding-bottom` instead?

Comment: depends on your needs and on how you're going to handle the background image size, because if you want it responsive (with background-size:cover) then you don't know exactly what the image dimensions will be

Comment: Responsive would be good. Hmm, but even with padding, that's not really responsive, is it? Basically, I'd like it to scale to fit horizontally (left-right), then show the full vertical dimension, whatever that happens to be - what could I use to achieve that?