# Bootstrap 3 and Responsive Background Images?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a responsive site using Bootstrap that has multiple full-width background images.

Here's a mockup of how it should look:

[image]

The idea is for each image to stretch to the width of the browser window, and then the height to be scaled accordingly to preserve the aspect ratio.

I've put up a JSFiddle of what I've got right now:

http://jsfiddle.net/SeFVV/

Currently, I've got multiple `<section>` tag, and I'm setting a background image with `background-size: cover` on each:

```
    #first {
        background: url(http://placehold.it/1350x890/37FDFC/&text=photo1) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        min-height: 800px;
        /*height: 800px;*/
        /*padding-bottom: 200px;*/
    }
```

As a hack, I'm setting min-width for each  so it's not really responsive.

If I don't set min-height, then each  simply shrinks to fit the elements inside, which is not what I want.

In a previous question, the answer suggested using multiple Bootstrap containers - are you meant to have multiple container divs normally? Also, that answer didn't really cover how to make it responsive, so that the width would fit, and the heigh would scale to preserve aspect ratio.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671572/multiple-stacked-full-width-background-images-with-bootstrap-3-0

Comment: @mb21 - The difference with that question is, I actually want it responsive (i.e. the width should fit the screen, and the height should scale to preserve the image's aspect ratio).

Comment: I don't know if that is possible.
Maybe your best option is create multiple sizes of that image and play with media queries, not easy and not "automatic" but that way will works.

Comment: If you want to resize the height of the container based on a background image then you will need to resort to javascript. I'd suggest taking a look at either [backstretch](http://responsivedesign.is/resources/javascript-jquery/back-stretch) or [any stretch](http://responsivedesign.is/resources/javascript-jquery/anystretch).  Alternatively set a class .section to each of your areas and update the min-height within media queries. Keeping those sizes uniform is probably advantageous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic  height of window by adding to your html and body tag height of 100%, and the section tags of the page(where you want to streach the background images).

Example:

```
html,body,section{height:100%;}
```

[Live Example](http://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/okJKL)